# slicing out multiples of nth element

Tags: arrays, perl, list, grep

I am having a list which has more than 10k elements. I want to remove every third element.

For example,

```
@testlists = qw (helloworld sessions first.cgi login localpcs depthhashes.cgi search view macros plugins ...) ;
```

I want to remove `first.cgi`, `depthhashses.cgi`, `macros` and so on from original array. Grep function is little bit slower. Please suggest me a faster grep search or any other similar subroutines . Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can think of a few solutions:

- Grep on index divisibility

  ```
  my $i = 0;
  @testlist = grep { ++$i % 3 } @testlist;
  ```
- repeated splicing

  ```
  for (my $i = 2; $i < $#testlist; $i += 2) {
    splice @testlist, $i, 1;
  }
  ```
- Copying with skipping

  ```
  my @output;
  # pre-extend the array for fewer reallocations
  $#output = @testlist * 2/3;
  @output = ();

  # FIXME annoying off-by one errors at the end that can add one undef
  for (my $i = 0; $i < @testlist; $i += 3) {
    push @output, @testlist[$i, $i+1];
  }
  ```

Ikegami has corrected and optimized the copying solution in his remarkable answer.

A benchmark with 1,000-element lists declares splicing the clear winner:

```
         Rate  slice   grep   copy splice
slice   790/s     --   -10%   -18%   -37%
grep    883/s    12%     --    -8%   -29%
copy    960/s    22%     9%     --   -23%
splice 1248/s    58%    41%    30%     --
```

(`slice` is mob's solution)

This is probably because it offloads most of the actual work into the C-level implementations, and avoids allocations and costly Perl-level operations.

With 10,000-element lists, the advantages shift towards the other solutions. Indeed, the splice solution has a very bad algorithmic complexity, because it moves all elements after all splicing position, meaning that the last element is moved nearly 3333 times:

```
         Rate splice  slice   grep   copy
splice 42.7/s     --   -35%   -42%   -49%
slice  65.3/s    53%     --   -12%   -23%
grep   74.2/s    74%    14%     --   -12%
copy   84.4/s    98%    29%    14%     --
```

Here is the [script I used for benchmarking](https://gist.github.com/latk/6558400).

Comment: You might be interested in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

amon's `copy` can be tweaked to be 30% faster!

```
my $i = 1;
my $j = 1;
while ($i < @a) {
   $a[++$j] = $a[$i+=2];
   $a[++$j] = $a[++$i];
}

$#a = $j-1 if @a>2;
```

And you can get even faster by avoid copying anything at all (though the result is a reference to an array). The longer the strings in each element, the better this will do.

```
my $i = 0;
my $ref = sub { \@_ }->( grep { ++$i % 3 } @a );
```

Results (10,000 elements):

```
>perl a.pl
           Rate splice_a splice_r  grep_a copy1_a copy1_r copy2_r copy2_a grep_r
splice_a 52.8/s       --      -0%    -51%    -54%    -56%    -66%    -66%   -68%
splice_r 52.9/s       0%       --    -51%    -54%    -55%    -66%    -66%   -68%
grep_a    107/s     103%     103%      --     -7%    -10%    -30%    -31%   -34%
copy1_a   115/s     118%     117%      7%      --     -3%    -25%    -26%   -30%
copy1_r   119/s     125%     124%     11%      3%      --    -23%    -23%   -27%
copy2_r   154/s     191%     190%     43%     34%     29%      --     -0%    -6%
copy2_a   154/s     192%     192%     44%     34%     30%      0%      --    -6%
grep_r    163/s     209%     209%     52%     42%     37%      6%      6%     --
```

Benchmark:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw( cmpthese );

my @testlist = qw( helloworld sessions first.cgi login localpcs depthhashes.cgi search view macros );
@testlist = ( @testlist ) x ( 10000 / @testlist );

sub grep_a { my @a = @testlist; my $i = 0; @a = grep { ++$i % 3 } @a; 1 }
sub copy1_a { my @a = @testlist;
   my @b;
   $#b = $#a; @b = (); # Does absolutely nothing in this benchmark because of optimisations in Perl.
   for (my $i = 0; $i < @a; $i += 3) {
      push @b, @a[$i, $i+1];
   }
   1
}
sub copy2_a { my @a = @testlist;
   my $i = 1;
   my $j = 1;
   while ($i < @a) {
      $a[++$j] = $a[$i+=2];
      $a[++$j] = $a[++$i];
   }
   $#a = $j-1 if @a>2;
   1
}
sub splice_a { my @a = @testlist;
   for (my $i = 2; $i < $#a; $i += 2) {
     splice @a, $i, 1;
   }
   1
}

sub grep_r { my $r = [ @testlist ]; my $i = 0; $r = sub { \@_ }->( grep { ++$i % 3 } @$r ); 1 }
sub copy1_r { my $r = [ @testlist ];
   my @b;
   $#b = $#$r; @b = (); # Does absolutely nothing in this benchmark because of optimisations in Perl.
   for (my $i = 0; $i < @$r; $i += 3) {
      push @b, @$r[$i, $i+1];
   }
   $r = \@b;
   1
}
sub copy2_r { my $r = [ @testlist ];
   my $i = 1;
   my $j = 1;
   while ($i < @$r) {
      $r->[++$j] = $r->[$i+=2];
      $r->[++$j] = $r->[++$i];
   }
   $#$r = $j-1 if @$r>2;
   1
}
sub splice_r { my $r = [ @testlist ];
   for (my $i = 2; $i < $#$r; $i += 2) {
     splice @$r, $i, 1;
   }
   1
}

cmpthese(-3, {
   grep_a => \&grep_a,
   copy1_a => \&copy1_a,
   copy2_a => \&copy2_a,
   splice_a => \&splice_a,

   grep_r => \&grep_r,
   copy1_r => \&copy1_r,
   copy2_r => \&copy2_r,
   splice_r => \&splice_r,
});
```

Comment: Is there significant difference between `sub { \@_ }->( grep { ++$i % 3 } @$r )` and `[ grep { ++$i % 3 } @$r ]`?

Comment: @mpapec, One is 50% faster than the other because it doesn't copy any scalars.

Comment: that's great, can you point to rationale behind it? perhaps list stays on heap, and functions just returns reference to what it see as `@_`?

Comment: huh? The rational behind not doing `$scalar2 = $scalar1;` is that it's faster not to do it.

Comment: @mpapec, No, the one I posted is [43% faster](http://pastebin.com/ijb5tGyj) than yours. Yours merely 10% faster than `grep_a` --I'm surprised is not the same-- whereas mine is 57% faster.

Comment: yes, your example is faster, but that's not the point. I was wandering why is so great difference between these two => http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=MwMud8qT and why `[..]` can't do same thing in terms of performance as `sub { \@_ }`

Comment: @mpapec, `[ EXPR ]` is basically the same as `do { my @anon = ( EXPR ); \@anon }`.  It does an assignment. `\@_` doesn't do an assignment. I don't know what else you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use an array slice.

```
@testlists = @testlists[ grep { ($_+1) % 3 } 0..$#testlists ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean about using grep but perhaps you mean something like this.

```
for $i (0 .. $#testlists) {
    if (($i % 3) == 2) {
        delete $testlists[$i];
    }
}

# Demonstrate the values.
foreach $e (@testlists) {
    print "$e\n";
}
```

Comment: From perldoc, `Although exists() will return false for deleted entries, deleting array elements never changes indices of existing values` and `Calling delete on array values is deprecated and likely to be removed in a future version of Perl.`

Comment: @mpapec I'm still an average user of Perl actually so thanks for the info.